# Put a range on the input of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java programming. I would like to know if there is a way that I can fill the array with integers from the keyboard(range: 10 to 65). Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)      
{
    //Keyboard Initialization
    Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //a.Declare an array to hold 10 intgers values
    int list[]=new int[10];     
    int i=0;
    //b.Fill the array with intgers from the keyboard(range: 10 to 50).
    System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 50: \n");
    list[i]= kbin.nextInt();
    if(10<=list[i] && list[i] <= 50)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=9;i++)
        {
            list [i] = kbin.nextInt();      
        }
    }
}
```

please help.Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `if(10<=list[i] && list[i] <= 50)` be `if(list[i] >= 10 && list[i] <= 50)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer is it the same thing?

Comment: I just read it as wrong that's all - my logic works that way :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you intent properly...

You need to loop until you have 10 valid numbers.  If a number entered by the user is out of range, then it needs to be discarded.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Keyboard Initialization
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

        //a.Declare an array to hold 10 intgers values
        int list[] = new int[10];
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 50: \n");
        while (i < 10) {
            //b.Fill the array with intgers from the keyboard(range: 10 to 50).
            int value = kbin.nextInt();
            if (value >= 10 && value <= 50) {
                list[i] = value;
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("!! Bad number !!");
            }
        }
        for (int value : list) {
            System.out.println("..." + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output...

```
    Input numbers from 10 to 50: 
1
!! Bad number !!
2
!! Bad number !!
3
!! Bad number !!
4
!! Bad number !!
5
!! Bad number !!
6
!! Bad number !!
7
!! Bad number !!
8
!! Bad number !!
9
!! Bad number !!
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
...10
...11
...12
...13
...14
...15
...16
...17
...18
...19
```

Comment: Something like that, but the array is still filled with number

Comment: What do you mean "still filled with number"?

Comment: because if the number that is entered by a user is invalid the list[something] will not show on the output. Is there a way that the whole array list will be filled with valid numbers without the program being discarded?

Comment: That's what the example does...I added some example output :)

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it...

```
System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 50: \n");
for(int i=0; i<10;)
{
    int k = kbin.nextInt();      
    if (k >= 10 && k <= 50)
    {
        list[i] = k;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, except, if the user fails to enter a valid number, the index of the array is increment regardless, leaving a empty value...

Comment: @MadProgrammer good point. fixed. Forces 10 digits. Not sure this is what the OP wants, but minor changes to tweak it to do something else.

Comment: Looks better then my idea ;) +1

Comment: is there a way that the empty value will be filled?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do.  But, I am guessing that you are trying to take the first 10 numbers the users enters?

One important thing to remember is that java (and other languages) uses 0 based indexing. So your for loop where i = 1, i <= 9; i++ I think that i should start at 0, but again I am not sure what you are going for here.

Comment: He does start at 0, before he enters the loop he fills index 0 with the first nextInt prior to the loop.

Comment: @Greg I am trying to fill the array with integers ranging from 10 to 50. I want to limit the range that the user will input.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question has been answered already but I noticed that no one provided or talked about the `.hasNext()` **regex** method so below I am providing an answer to this question using **regex expression**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main3 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int list [] = new int [10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            if (sc.hasNext("([1-4][0-9])?(50)?")) {
                list[i] = sc.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Entered value is out of range 10 - 50. Please enter a valid number");
                i --;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(list[9]);
    }
}
```